# How can I divide up an XML element list and parse it with javscript according the date of the node?

Tags: javascript, xml

Write now I'm working with the following XML

```
<LIST>
 <DAY>

    <DATE>
     October 17th, 2019
    </DATE>

    <SONG>
        <SONGNAME>

        </SONGNAME>
        <ARTIST>

        </ARTIST>
        <LINK>

        </LINK>
        <ART>

        </ART>
    </SONG>

<SONG>
        <SONGNAME>

        </SONGNAME>
        <ARTIST>

        </ARTIST>
        <LINK>

        </LINK>
        <ART>

        </ART>
    </SONG>
<SONG>
        <SONGNAME>

        </SONGNAME>
        <ARTIST>

        </ARTIST>
        <LINK>

        </LINK>
        <ART>

        </ART>
    </SONG>
 </DAY>

</LIST>
```

Basically, I want to only parse and make a list out of items from a specific date. The idea would be for there to be multiple songs posted and I want to get all the songs in a list for that date. However, there doesn't seem to be a way to select only that days list of songs using xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DAY").  Does anyone have a suggestion I can use for this?

Is the solution to just create different XML's for each day? That's really not optimal.

This is the javascript I'm basically trying to do. I know it doesn't work, but I need something that follows this logic.

```
function getSongList(xml) {
  var x, i, xmlDoc, txt;
  xmlDoc = xml.responseXML;
  txt = "";
  z = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DAY");


  for (i = 0; i< z.length; i++) {
    txt += "<a href='#'' class='list-group-item'>";
    txt += z[i].childNodes[1].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    txt += " - ";
    txt += z[i].childNodes[1].childNodes[1].nodeValue;
    txt += "</a>";
  }
  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = txt;
}
```

Comment: Can you post more than one node so we have some idea how the songs are grouped.

Comment: okay i've updated it

Comment: i figured it out. You just do  x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DAY"); then z = x[0].getElementsByTagName("SONGNAME"); I was missing the [0].

Answer (score 1):

To get child elements of a getElementsByTagName call, you simply do

```
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("DAY");
```

followed by

```
z = x[0].getElementsByTagName("SONGNAME");
```

The [0] is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Node, you could use - https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-js which converts it into JSON which is simpler to handle using just the dot notations. Only issue I see with this approach is if this process is repetitive in short duration, then this you will notice small delay as it would transform one platform neutral object to another. 
On the other hand if you keep using index numbers to populate `txt` variable you may find it difficult to maintain after just a few future enhancement.